# Java: Multiple Declarations of Local Variable in Loop

Tags: java, variables, initialization, local, declaration

Why can I declare a local variable in this for loop multiple times by including the `int` prefix in the loop?

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            int num = 5;
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Contrast with this (variable can be used throughout class):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            num = 5;
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int obj;`: is this supposed to be `int num;`?

Comment: Oops, yes, that is supposed to be `int num;`. Edited.

Comment: I want to know why I'm allowed to write `int num = 5;` in the for loop in the first example as it goes through the loop multiple times. Does it reinitialize the variable?